# Any subspace of locally compact space is locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

I can show that *closed* subspaces of loaclly compact spaces are locally compact. To show that if K is a closed subset of *X, x ∈ K*, and *U* is a compact nbhd of *x* in *X*, then *U ∩ K* is a compact nbhd of *x* in *K*.

To show that U∩K is compact, let *V* be an open cover of *U ∩ K*. *K* is closed in *X*, so *X∖K* is open; let *W = V ∪ {X∖K}*. *W* is a collection of open sets. Then I can show *W* covers *U*.

So there exists some finite $W_0$ ⊆ W covers *U*, since *U* is compact. Clearly $W_0$ covers *U ∩ K*. If *X∖K* ∉ $W_0$, then $W_0$ ⊆ *V*, and I have the required. Even if *X∖K* ∈ $W_0$, after throwing it away what’s left will still cover *U ∩ K*.

But this proof is specific if I have a **closed** subspace. I want an answer for any subspace in general (or counter example)

Comment: A subspace $Y$ of a locally compact Hausdorff space is locally compact iff $Y= O \cap C$ where $O$ is an open and $C$ is a closed subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is negative. Note that $\mathbb Q$ is *not* locally compact with respect to the topology that it gets from $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Could you please give a proof of the same?

Comment: Do you mean the fact that every open subset of a locally compact space is also locally compact?

Comment: Yes. I mean it covers itself. But is that all?

Comment: If $X$ is locally compact and $A$ is an open subset of $X$, then let $N$ be a neighborhood of a point $p\in A$. Then, since $A$ is open, $V$ is also a neighborhood of $p$ in $X$. But then, since $X$ is locally compact, $V$ contains some compact neighborhood of $p$ in $X$, which, since $V\subset A$; is also a neighborhood of $p$ in $A$.

Comment: @irenedovichi It is not a *vector* subspace. This question is about *topological* subspaces.